# Show UTC date under achievements

Tags: feature-request, time

On the Achievements drop down it shows the time, example

```
UTC TIME 21:47
```

However the date does not appear to accompany this, even upon hovering. Can the date be added here? It would be nice when the date click over to know what day it is clicking over to.

Comment: For this you have your [computer clock](http://i.stack.imgur.com/60Qtb.png). The time display is meant only to let you know the difference between your local time and the time used by SE, so personally can't see much benefit from making it full date.

Comment: See my edit for some more, less sarcastic, details. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the computer clock cannot help because it is a different time zone, hence the need in the first place

Comment: Date still can be deducted easily enough. Anyway, guess having the full date and time showing as tooltip won't hurt.

Comment: The time info is shown to help with knowing the day turnover. I don't see how showing the date will help for the site *per se*. The site is not focused on being a clock. The time is only an auxiliary feature to help users use site-specific features better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I have added a clock in Windows

[image: utc]